# How to install cURL and grep in Debian based image (postgres:10)?

Tags: postgresql, docker, curl, debian, apt-get

I'm using the postgres:10 official image (restoring a db with OIDs that are not supported in latest) and I need to also install curl and grep.

The docs say that the (new versions at least) default to using Debian for the base image.

So I'd think that the following installs curl and grep

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:10

WORKDIR /db

COPY ./start.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y grep
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

EXPOSE 5432

CMD ["postgres"]
```

But the build process yields the below.

I am running Apple M3 but didn't think that would matter. Any tips?

```
=> ERROR [db 4/5] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y grep                                                                                                                   0.7s
------
 > [db 4/5] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y grep:
0.117 Ign:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg InRelease
0.130 Ign:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
0.133 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
0.145 Ign:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release
0.147 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
0.149 Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
0.165 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
0.165 Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.165 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main Sources
0.180 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
0.183 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
0.183 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 Sources
0.189 Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.197 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main Sources
0.199 Ign:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
0.199 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
0.206 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 Sources
0.208 Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.210 Ign:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports Release
0.218 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
0.223 Ign:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.228 Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.231 Ign:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
0.235 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
0.239 Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
0.242 Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.248 Ign:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.248 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main Sources
0.249 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
0.258 Ign:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main all Packages
0.258 Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.261 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 Sources
0.269 Ign:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main arm64 Packages
0.269 Err:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
0.269   404  Not Found
0.269 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main Sources
0.278 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 Sources
0.283 Ign:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.288 Ign:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main Sources
0.291 Ign:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
0.296 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 Sources
0.305 Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
0.305 Err:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main Sources
0.305   404  Not Found [IP: 72.32.157.246 80]
0.313 Ign:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/11 Sources
0.315 Ign:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.325 Ign:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main all Packages
0.341 Ign:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main arm64 Packages
0.351 Ign:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.360 Ign:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
0.369 Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
0.385 Ign:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.392 Ign:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main all Packages
0.492 Ign:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main arm64 Packages
0.501 Ign:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.511 Ign:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
0.521 Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
0.532 Ign:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.543 Ign:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main all Packages
0.554 Ign:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main arm64 Packages
0.562 Ign:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.570 Ign:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
0.585 Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
0.593 Ign:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.601 Ign:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main all Packages
0.615 Ign:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main arm64 Packages
0.622 Ign:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.633 Err:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
0.633   404  Not Found
0.644 Err:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
0.644   404  Not Found
0.653 Ign:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.664 Ign:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main all Packages
0.674 Err:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main arm64 Packages
0.674   404  Not Found
0.683 Reading package lists...
0.695 W: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
0.695 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
0.695 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
0.695 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
0.695 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
0.695 E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/stretch-pgdg/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 72.32.157.246 80]
0.695 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
0.695 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
0.695 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
0.695 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
0.695 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: That's not a supported debian release, upgrade: https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/

Comment: PostgreSQL version 10 is not supported either, that version is EOL since November 2022. Archeology is very interesting, but not something you wish to use for new software development

Comment: @FrankHeikens, yeah, looks like that's the case. Trying to restore from a backup that used OIDs in the dump, which are deprecated in newer versions.

Comment: `The use of OIDs in user tables is considered deprecated` This message came with version 8.1, released in 2005.

Comment: Well, the restore works with image `postgres:10`. Unsure if there's a diff between image and version.  I'm able to query the db and all post restore to confirm. Just can't install curl and grep.

Comment: So dump the db using a modern pg_dump and restore it into a modern version. Do read all the release notes though, some things have been tightened up since then.